# np.interp not referencing correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Somewhat new to python here. Just trying to analyze some data for a project. Here I am trying  to find the 50% value of a dataset labeled second  that is normalized to the max of 100. I am getting the last value (775) rather than the value that associates with 50. Both values come from chopped up excel data.

fiftypercent=np.interp(50, y, x)

[Image of x and y plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYHbX.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SqEl.png)

Answer (score 1):

The code in your image is doing `np.interp(50, x, y)`, not `np.interp(50, y, x)` as you have in the question, so you need to swap those. Also, `np.interp()` requires the x-coordinate values (your `y`) to be sorted. You can use `np.argsort()` to get the indices that will sort `y`, and use them to get `x` in the same order.